Topological illustration of spacetime dilation: which function should I use for isometric lines spacing?
Scientific popularization, when it comes to illustrating spacetime dilation around massive objects, often relies on the description of a two-dimensional square-grid, which can be regarded as a cross-section of the illustrated area, which is then bent in a third perpendicular dimension to describe dilation, hence somewhat misleading.
In an attempt to reconciliate mental and visual representations and maybe to go through with this spacetime transversal cut idea, I am currently working on a topological animated map including four massive objects in motion.
This is draft v0.2
The goal would be to achieve a small galactic system descriptive illustration.
For now it is a schematic description of gravitational potential and I’d like it to be a description of time dilation, which will require far more isometric lines. Technical difficulties, due to the boolean objects used to generate isometric lines, highly dilate rendering time and have to be solved first.
Also, and this is my question, I wonder : what mathematical function should I use ?
Time dilation proportion on large scales can be approximated with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}$ with R the distance to the geometrical center of a massive object in graphical arbitrary units. But I also want the illustration to take length dilation into account.
If we consider a cross-section graphical description of one massive body’s influence on its environment's time dilation, away from any other influences and with a graphical scale such that the Schwarzschild radius sphere can be treated as one point or less, we get something like this.

Enumerating circles from the center, the n-th circle’s graphical radius is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
And when $n \to +\infty$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \to 2\sqrt{n}$, with a negligible $\zeta{(\frac{1}{2})}$.
I guess it is the same kind of correction astronomers use for theorical galactic orbital speeds calculation, but I could not find a description of those.
What formula would you recommand for the simulation to be descriptive of space dilation ?
(the question is not (yet) regarding bodies trajectories and interactions)
